# How can I constantly check collision between page elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented the algorithm, but what I am facing is how can I check constantly whether the element has hit other elements.

Example:

div id='water' when hits div id='orange' should alert , should I use jQuery setInterval :s or is there any other way to keep the function live ?

Comment: Your div are moving on your page? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i have implemented the algorithm. what im stuck is, how can I keep calling the function :S other than setTimeOut

Comment: yes, my divs are moving on the page, but I want the function to detect the collision any time they hit together

Comment: Search for DOMAttrModified and other DOM events.

Comment: You can't fire the "collision" event on the DIVs. You should use a function that checks every now and then for collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **setInterval()**. Here's a little sample.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Checks collisions every second
    setInterval(function(){checkCollisions()},1000);
});


function checkCollisions() {
    // Do your checks
}
```